# Cloud Function Permissions (403 when invoking from another cloud function)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to invoke a cloud function (CF2) from another (CF1). However, I keep getting a 403.

My issue is figuring out which service account to be a "cloud function invoker" of CF2.

I assumed that the cloud function service agent of CF1 is the one that's required, but this hasn't been working.

Comment: You will most likely need to configure your [IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) for invoker. Additionally, you can take a look at the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam), which explains the service accounts used for Cloud Functions and Troublshooting methods for Cloud Function permission errors. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm going through right now.

Comment: Do you still have issue with this? If yes, what is your latest status?

Comment: Yeah, still having issues with it. I've set up the cloud function invoker to be the service account with the proper role. Still throwing 403's. Going to see what else I can do.

Comment: When an unauthenticated caller sends a request to the function, they will see a 401/403 status code response. You should ensure that allUsers has roles/cloudfunctions.invoker role in the function's IAM. You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation). What I shared with you earlier is a full list of IAM roles and their associated permissions used in Cloud Funtions.

Comment: Yeah, I gave the service account "cloud function invoker" permissions. If I do allUsers, anyone would be able to access it, which I don't want.

Comment: I posted an answer for what needs to be done when using Cloud Function-to-function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function):**

### Receiving Function

**First, you'll need to configure the receiving function to accept requests from the calling function:**

> Grant the Cloud Functions Invoker (roles/cloudfunctions.invoker) role to the calling function identity on the receiving function. By default, this identity is PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

**Use the gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding command:**

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding RECEIVING_FUNCTION \
  --member='serviceAccount:CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY' \
  --role='roles/cloudfunctions.invoker'
```

**where RECEIVING_FUNCTION is the receiving function, and CALLING_FUNCTION_IDENTITY is the calling function identity.**

---

### Calling Function

**In the calling function, you'll need to:**

> 1. Create a Google-signed OAuth ID token with the audience (aud) set to the URL of the receiving function.
> 2. Include the ID token in an Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the function.

```
# Requests is already installed, no need to add it to requirements.txt
import requests

def calling_function(request):
  # Make sure to replace variables with appropriate values
  receiving_function_url = 'https://REGION-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/RECEIVING_FUNCTION'

  # Set up metadata server request
  # See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
  metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='

  token_request_url = metadata_server_token_url + receiving_function_url
  token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

  # Fetch the token
  token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
  jwt = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")

  # Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
  receiving_function_headers = {'Authorization': f'bearer {jwt}'}
  function_response = requests.get(receiving_function_url, headers=receiving_function_headers)

  return function_response.content
```

More info can be found **[here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function)**

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I created two services accounts:

   ```
   gcloud iam service-accounts create function-one --desplay-name function-one
   gcloud iam service-accounts create function-two --display-name function-two
   ```
2. I assigned the necessary roles to my services accounts:

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my_project --member serviceAccount:function-one@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my_project --member serviceAccount:function-two@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
   ```
3. I created two cloud functions on the Google Cloud console [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console). When I created the cloud functions, under "Environment variables, networking, timeouts and more", "Service acoount" I assigned to each cloud function a service account created in step 1.

   ```
   def hello_gcs_generic_one(request):

        import requests
        print ('Hello from cloud function one')

        response = requests.post("https://us-central1-my_project.cloudfunctions.net/function-two")

        if response.status_code != 200:
            exit("Could not call function! :(")



   def hello_gcs_generic_two(request):

       print ('Hello from cloud function two')
   ```
4. I tested calling the function-one "TESTING/TEST THE FUNCTION" :

   Function One Loggs:

   ```
       Function execution started
       Hello from cloud function one
       Function execution took 2219 ms, finished with status code: 200
   ```

   Function Two Loggs:

   ```
       Function execution started
       Hello from cloud function two
       Function execution took 18 ms, finished with status code: 200
   ```