# firebase functions calls to GCP - with a 403 - IAM blocks the call

Tags: javascript, python, firebase, gcloud

Hello in this awesome 2022, that WILL be better!

here's the case we got and the problem we are facing:

1. We have two parts of the same project - firebase (firebase functions created in javascript - project A) as well as google cloud (cloud function created in python - project B).
2. From the FirebaseFunction part (A) we are sending a POST into the CloudFunction (B)
3. We want this request to be authenticated with the IAM on GCP side (B)

And so in project A:

```
  const firebase = require("firebase-admin"); 
  const botInformURL = "URLTOHIT";
  const token = await firebase.auth().createCustomToken("XXX-notification-system"); 
  const output = await axios.post(botInformURL, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ additionalMessage }),
```

From the google cloud Platform (for CloudFunctions - in project B setup) I have added service account email ((...)projectA(...)iam.gserviceaccount.com) as a Cloud Functions Invoker (tried admin as well - without success)

And now - I am being blocked on the GCP with a 403.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Could you confirm if Cloud Functions Invoker permission is set to the "allUsers" user in the Cloud Functions page?

Comment: Actually not --> I have added the invoker permissions to the nameprojectA@projectA.iam.gserviceaccount.com as I assumed this will be enough and we do not want to publicly expose this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

When an **unauthenticated caller sends a request to the Cloud Function, they will see a 401/403 status code response**. In this scenario, the way out is to ensure that **‘allUsers’ has ‘roles/cloudfunctions.invoker’ role** in the Cloud Function's IAM. You may refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam) for more on this.

But yes, you are correct, if you use **‘allUsers’ it would expose the endpoint publicly and anyone would be able to access it**.

If you want to avoid this, you have to follow the below steps:

```
From the receiving function:

 1. You need to configure the receiving function to accept requests from
    the calling function.  
 2. Use the gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding command.

From the calling function:

 1. Create a Google-signed OAuth ID token with the audience (aud) set to
    the URL of the receiving function.
 2. Include the ID token in an
    Authorization: Bearer ID_TOKEN header in the request to the
    function.
```

You may also refer to the [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142729/cloud-function-permissions-403-when-invoking-from-another-cloud-function) for more information.

Comment: Thank You :) 

The problem I have now is - I do not know how to generate the right token in the firebase. I assume there is a simple way using the firebase-admin library.

Comment: You may have a look on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-googleid).