# Call cloud function through another in the same project without allUsers permission

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 functions in the same google cloud functions project (myfunction1 and myfunction2.

```
exports.myfunction1 = async (req, res) => {

 await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                        url: 'https://SERVER-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction2',
                        timeout: 15000,
                        headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                },
                                data: myjson
                        }).then(response => {
                           console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.error("catch error");
                            console.error(err);
                     })
            }
```

It is works fine, but only if I configure invokers permission for allUsers. If I remove this permission, e receive 403 code error. Not sounds good keep this permisson activate, because the function is exposed. I tried solve with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142729/cloud-function-permissions-403-when-invoking-from-another-cloud-function) and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_programmatically), but, no sucess.

**Edit1:**

```
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
const auth = new GoogleAuth();

const targetAudience = 'https://SERVER-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction2'

const url = '??????????';

async function request() {
  console.info('request ${url} with target audience ${targetAudience}');
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.info(res.data);
}
```

I'm trying using this code, but, who is const url?

Comment: Url is the same as the target audience: it's the URL of the function to call. For Cloud Run and Cloud Functions, URL and Audience must be the same.

Comment: Not worked. 

TypeError: Cannot create property 'headers' on string 'https://SERVER-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction2'
    at IdTokenClient.requestAsync (/workspace/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:358:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

But I found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let audience = 'https://SERVER-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction2';
let token_request_url = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=' + audience;

var token_response = await axios.get(token_request_url, { headers: {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'} });

let token_auth = token_response.data;

axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: audience,
        timeout: 15000,
          headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + token_auth
              },
                data: myJSON
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting code is okay. Please consider adding some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You must perform [service to service authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service). You can find a great tutorial in the Cloud Run page (ok you use Cloud Functions but the underlying infrastructure is the same and the doc is better).

You also have to be aware about the [Functions identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) and how to change them (or to grant the current service account the correct permission)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edit the question.